# SQL: Distinct count in where clause?

Tags: sql, count

My order table looks like this:

```
id   fk_customer
1    34
2    34
3    34
4    7
5    7
6    8
```

I would like to select only those customers who have more than 2 orders.

This doesnt work however:

`SELECT * FROM order WHERE COUNT DISTINCT fk_customer > 2`

Please advice!

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT fk_customer, COUNT(*)   
FROM dbo.[Order]
GROUP BY fk_customer
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

`Order` is a reserved word in most SQL based database systems - bad choice for a table name.... in SQL Server, you need to put it in square brackets to make it clear it's an object name (not the reserved word) to be used.

Comment: In reality my table is a left join with three other tables

Comment: @jorrebor: yes - and where's the problem with that??

Comment: sorry i was still editing that comment. I tried several variations on what you proposed. But nothing gives the right result, please see my upcoming edit.

Comment: ok that did it, i had some troubles "translating" my real problem. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT fk_customer FROM orders
GROUP BY fk_customer
HAVING COUNT(id) > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use `COUNT` in the `WHERE` clause, SQL will throw an exception.  You can only use an aggregate function if it is within a sub-query contained in a `HAVING` clause or a select list.

```
SELECT fk_customer, COUNT(*)    
  FROM dbo.[Order] 
 GROUP 
    BY fk_customer 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fk_customer, COUNT(fk_customer) FROM [order]
GROUP BY fk_customer HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```